# How can I get rid of the "The target assembly contains no service types" error message in VS2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, wcf, debugging

I've got a Client/Server wcf application

My executable doesn't define any `ServiceContract`, it doesn't even have a reference to `System.ServiceModel` (*but instead has a reference to an assembly which contains the connection logic to the server*)

I've another assembly, which is referenced by my EXE, which contains a `ServiceContract`.

It used to work fine. Yesterday, I've played a lot with my project settings (*partial trust, full trust, deployment settings, and so on*) and now, each and every time I launch my client, I've got the following message box :

> Microsoft WCF Service Host
>    The target assembly contains no service types.
>    You may need to adjust the Code Access Security policy of this assembly.

Then VS freezes for 1 minute, and eventually lets me debug my program as usual.

I've found [a post on this problem](http://cs.rthand.com/blogs/blog_with_righthand/archive/2008/03/10/_2200_The-target-assembly-contains-no-service-types.--You-may-need-to-adjust-the-Code-Access-Security-policy-of-this-assembly_2E002200_-annoyance.aspx), but the solution doesn't apply in my situation.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

It's always like that. You search for 2 hours, you eventually end up posting on SO, and 5 minutes later, you find the answer.

In the [WCF Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668754.aspx) tab of the properties of the project defining the `ServiceContract`,
**there's a checkbox labelled "Start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the same solution" that I unchecked.**

I've no idea how it has been checked in the first place.

Anyway, that solved my problem. See the [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668754.aspx) for this project setting.

Comment: Where is this in visual studio 2010?

Comment: @Jonathan: my bet is that you're not looking at the properties of the correct project. You need to select the project *defining* the contract; not the one implementing it nor the one calling it.

Comment: Thanks Brann, you were right about it. It is in the same place in 2010

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue and the project defining the contract doesn't have a WCF options tab. It's infuriating...

Comment: I'm looking in my WCF Web Service Project, my actual WCF service project.  The properties have nothing to that effect.

Comment: This solved my issue. I think it's because I have the service defined in a different project from which it's implemented.

Answer (score 12):

Just in case anyone else is looking for an answer, another cause of this error can be if you happen to have an `App.config` file in a project that is a Class Library that has a `<system.serviceModel>` section.

I moved service code out of a project that was an executable to a different project but accidentally left the old `App.config` file. My new project, which was a Console application programatically configured and started WCF, but because the old `App.config` file was in the referenced assembly, I would get that cryptic dialog box even when debugging the Console application.

Took about 12 hours to track this one down since I didn't realize that VS debugger checks all referenced assemblies for App.config which have WCF services configured.

Answer (score 9):

To determine project with this problem find string 3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699 in your project files.

Example: `<ProjectTypeGuids>{3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>`

Then turn off project option **"WCF Options/Start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the same solution"**

Comment: While this solution might resolve the matter for some folks, at least in vs2015 it will remove "Publish" from the context menu when right-clicking on the WCF project...

Comment: Yes this will help us find which project we have mistakenly checked the "Start WCF Service Host when ..." as @Brann pointed out. I am using the following command to find which project has the setting: c:\MyProjects>findstr /s /m "3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699" *.csproj

Answer (score 4):

Some blogs say, it might have happend because of copying the project from a different branch, that overrides GUIDs... so just delete them as explained in [this blog.](http://kalirajanl.wordpress.com/2013/02/19/wcf-annoying-error/)

Comment: From VS2015 removing de Guid, went the project invalid

Answer (score 2):

This error can also be caused by a wrong service name in your config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyServiceLibrary.WrongServiceName">
...
```

Check your config file and be sure the service name is correct.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was, because one of the normal class library project (that was referenced by the WCF service library) had this in it's .csproj file:

```
<ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699}">
        <WcfProjectProperties>
          <AutoStart>True</AutoStart>
        </WcfProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

Changing this to False solved the problem.
This answer was already there, but make sure that you checked all projects, not just the WCF service library one.

Answer (score 1):

I also went through the same kind of problem and searched for hours to get rid of this particular error. Finally i did find out a way out of it.

When you come across this particular problem, you **try to run your both server and client application as *administrator***, and change the **WPF properties** of project.

When you click the WPF properties of the project, you will find a build option. In build option, there is a option called *PLATFORM TARGET*, in which you can change the platform target to *x86*. Also note that in case of *x84*, you need to set it to *x84*.

Now **run your project from console**, i.e. go to the folder where your projects are saved and in **the bin of client, you will find a folder *debug* where you will get your console application**. You should now be able to run the application successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread. Just remove any commandline arguments from the Debug section in Options. That helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another solution since this message seems to have multiple causes. Removing the following GUID from the ProjectTypeGuids tag in the project file resolved the issue.

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was creating new service from the scratch. So I deleted the class and interface created by VS and created `IHelloService` interface and `HelloService` class. I got this error because I forgot to inherit the interface from the class. After I added like `class HelloService:IHelloService` it works.