# Error debugging unit test in VS 2013 using Resharper

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, nunit, resharper

I am trying to debug a `nunit` unit test using Resharper in Visual Studio 2013.

I can run the test successfully although when I attempt to debug the test inside VS using Resharper I get the below warning msg.

*"Microsoft WCF Service Host"*

*"The target assembly contains no service types. You may need to adjust the Code Access Security policy of this assembly."*

The test does not fail and Visual Studio said it is "Running" although no break points are hit (in the test) nor does it throw any kind of exception or error.

Has anyone encounter this and know what a solution is?

[image: Error: The target assembly contains no service types. You may need to adjust the Code Access Security policy of this assembly.]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for anyone else interested.

[How can I get rid of the "The target assembly contains no service types" error message in VS2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564541/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-the-target-assembly-contains-no-service-types-error-m)

I had 1 project in a solution of around 90 which had the WCF Option enabled.